To what extent can likelihood methods be used for functional responses?
Let's suppose that we are working with a functional data set, $Y_i(t)$, $Y_i\in L^2[0,1]$, $1\le i\le n$. If we were working with univariate or even multivariate data set, likelihood methods would provide tools for tasks such as parameter estimation, clustering, hypothesis testing, and so on. We can describe likelihood functions for univariate and multivariate data since common models have tractable probability density functions.
To my knowledge, though, density functions describing the behavior of functional data are problematic due to functional data being infinite-dimensional. For instance, Gaussian processes are described by the distribution of $(Y_1(t_1), Y_1(t_2), \ldots, Y_1(t_m))$, or the distribution of the response vector of $Y_1$ when evaluated at an arbitrary finite collection of points. They may also be described in terms of a Karhunen-Loeve/functional principal component expansion with i.i.d. Gaussian loadings for the expansion. A PDF for an infinite sequence of Gaussian random variables does not seem to make sense in either of these specifications of the Gaussian process distribution. The only way someone might work with likelihood-based methods is to work with, say, the first $K$ terms of the K-L expansion, in which case you are working with something that does not mean anything as $K \to \infty$.
And for what it's worth, while I see discussions about likelihoods in, say, scalar-on-function regression, I do not see discussion in papers or books using likelihoods when the response itself is a function. Asymptotic methods, permutation or bootstrapping methods, and working with the geometry of Hilbert spaces seem to dominate the statistical methods.
But I'm newer to functional data methods, so perhaps there are likelihood-based methods for functional responses that I'm missing?

right: when we say "probability density function", the precise measure-theoretic interpretation is "density with respect to the Lebesgue measure", and indeed the Lebesgue measure does not exist in infinite dimensions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure
